# MATLAB 2007b, Win64...error message generated

Tags: matlab

**Source code**

```
[namefile,pathname]=uigetfile('*.*','Select AVI video');
if namefile~=0
    video_file_name = sprintf('%s%s',pathname,namefile);
    disp('Input file has been selected.');
else
    error('No valid file has been selected.');
end
mov= aviread(video_file_name);
fileinfo= aviinfo(video_file_nae);
<br/>
```

**error msg is** :

> Error using ==> readavi
>  Unable to locate decompressor to
>   decompress video stream

Comment: Did you try installing a codec pack?

Comment: please tell me which one to install, coz in the 2006 version I installed cvid, xvid.. it did not work ... would appreciate your guidance.

Comment: I suggest you try the K-Lite Codec Pack. But I'm not sure it will work. Maybe it could be a Matlab issue on that version, who knows, right? One thing I remember is that some codecs that work on a 32 bits Matlab version will not be found on a 64 bits version. If you're using 64 bits, maybe you could try a 32 bits version to see if it works.

Comment: still the same error after Installing the k-lite codec pack

Comment: What about 32 vs 64 bits?

Comment: i have tried using 64, as far as 32 is concerned I cannot find one over the internet, I would appreciate if u can provide me the link for 32

Comment: Doesn't your Matlab installation media have both 64 and 32 bit versions?

Comment: ya they do have... but what about that?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you, were you asking for the link to the 32 bits version of the codecs?

Comment: Yes I wanted the link to download a 32 bit version, by the way 1 more ques.. how to determine the bit for a installed windows.. its really a problem coz i totally new to MATLAB, and I need serious help

Comment: Well, I don't have the link for the 32 bit version. As to determine if you are on 32/64 bits, right click on Computer and choose Properties and read the system info, it's there.

Comment: Ya its 64 , i know that, bu problem does not seem to go away....
So would request you to help with a simple code which can help in reading a video file in 2007b or similar

Comment: Sorry, I don't have such code. Take a look at the documentation, it generally provides simple demo codes that should work.